# PhpStorm Missing property's type declaration on protected property

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I have class `\App\Console\Kernel` which extends from vendor class `\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel`. In vendor class there is `$commands` protected property with no type declaration, so in my own class I could not declare property type.

```
protected $commands = [
        // commands ...
];
```

But PhpStorm gives me next error:

> Missing property's type declaration
>
> Inspection info: Reports the properties that have no type declaration.

What to do?

Comment: I suggest reporting this to PhpStorm devs at their Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI. But before that: what IDE version do you run? If it's 2020.1 or older -- please check it in 2020.2 EAP build (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/)

Comment: I'm using 2020.2 and getting the same problem

Answer (score 8):

As of `PHP` `7.4` you can declare types on properties. So you could declare your property like this, hard typing it to an array.

```
protected array $commands = [];
```

`Laravel` is backwards compatible to `PHP` `7.1.3` or `7.2.5` depending on the version of `Laravel` and therefor does not implement this, so some classes that deal with inheritance you can not do this, as i remember `fillable`, `guarded` etc on models. As you describe it, also in your case.

The `PHPStorm` inspection is a suggestion and is not breaking, it is just trying to make you use `PHP` `7.4` features, if you are not running `7.4` i would recommend setting `PHPStorm` to the correct version of `PHP`.

Comment: As i described with the second paragraph :) but the ide wants him to type it. "so some classes that deal with inheritance and similar you can not do this"

Comment: You can disable this in the PHPStorm: Settings | Editor | Inspection | Type compatibility | Missing properties type declaration